# TLS 1.3 server_handshake_traffic_secret calculation

Tags: tls, server

I'm currently reading the [Transport Layer Security (TLS) Protocol Version 1.3](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-tls-tls13-28).

In section 4.3.1 (Encrypted Extensions) it says

> In all handshakes, the server MUST send the EncryptedExtensions
> message immediately after the ServerHello message. This is the first
> message that is encrypted under keys derived from the
> server_handshake_traffic_secret.

How exactly is that **server_handshake_traffic_secret** calculated? Where does it come from?

I try to find out how all the application-data (e.g. certificate) in the server-hello is encrypted.

It should have something to do with an [HKDF-Extract function](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-tls-tls13-28#section-7.1). In the client-hello there is a random byte-string and a filled key-exchange extension. I assume that the (first) use of HKDF during the server-hello must base on that. But how exactly?

Comment: Did you check section 7.1?

Comment: Yes! (I've hyperlinked it in my question.) The first argument of the function *Derive-Secret* is *Secret*. What is Secret?

Comment: It is clearly written there: "Derive-Secret's Secret argument is indicated by the incoming
      arrow.  For instance, the Early Secret is the Secret for
      generating the client_early_traffic_secret."

Comment: Okay Early Secret is the Secret for the first Derive-Secret-Call. Early Secret is computed with HKDF-Extract using PSK. What PSK? There is no PSK in the very first client-hello.

Comment: Read the section carefully, the PSK is initially some zero bytes: *If a given secret is not available, then the 0-value consisting of a string of Hash.length bytes set to zeros is used*

Comment: Wait, what? But how is this useful? How is this 'secret'? ... Btw. please feel welcome to post your comment as an answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

maybe this [pdf](https://eprint.iacr.org/2015/914.pdf) will help you.
client and server will use DH result as PMS, just like TLS1.2 use DH result as pre-masterkey, then the middler can't know the encrypt key.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

**server_handshake_traffic_secret** is generated as Section 7.1 of the RFC. This is later used in generating verify data of Finished message.
See page 72 of RFC which state

```
 The key used to compute the Finished message is computed from the
   Base Key defined in Section 4.4 using HKDF (see Section 7.1).
   Specifically:

   finished_key =
       HKDF-Expand-Label(BaseKey, "finished", "", Hash.length)
```

Here Base Key is nothing but **server_handshake_traffic_secret**.
In TLS 1.3 server generates following.

- handshake secret : This is later used in generating application secret key.
- client handshake traffic secret: For use in Finished message as explained above.
- server handshake traffic secret: For use in Finished message as explained above.
  Below are used to used to encrypt the extension.
- client handshake key:
- server handshake key:
- client handshake IV:
- server handshake IV: